# Number theoretic function related to totient

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function, multiplicative-function

I'm doing an excercise in Alan Baker's book *A Concise Introduction to the Theory of Numbers*, and I'm confused about the method spelled out for one question. I'll quote it here:

> Let $a$ run through all the integers with $1\leq a\leq n$ and $(a,n)=1$. Show that $f(n)=\frac1n\sum a$ satisfies $\sum_{d|n}f(d)=\frac12(n+1)$. Hence prove that $f(n)=\frac12\phi(n)$ for $n>1$.

My issue is this: I can prove the end result, but not using the intermediate step suggested. It's just clear that $2f(n)=\phi(n)$, because $n-a$ runs through all the same values as $a$ (assuming $n>1$), so you get $\phi(n)$ copies of $n$, and then divide by $n$. I can then use that fact to prove the suggested intermediate step about summing $f(d)$ over the divisors.

It seems that I'm not doing what the exercise suggests. Does anyone see how the author intended for this problem to be done? Is there some nice combinatorial argument or something for the formula $\sum_{d|n}f(d)=\frac12(n+1)$ that I'm just not seeing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like the problem with your book is that it's too concise.  Is there a reason you have to read that particular book or can you use one with more details, with exposition a little less terse?

Comment: Well, I may decide to retreat to a simpler one, but I am enjoying the book. I've worked through several more elementary number theory books, and sometimes I get stuck. This book in particular has got a chapter about quadratic forms that I'm keen to get to, and I enjoy at least trying to work through all the details. I got through all the problems in the first chapter without needing help, and maybe I'll run aground soon. For now, I'm still trying. :)

Comment: I gotcha, just asking.

Comment: Try to apply Mobius inversion.

Comment: Well, according to Mobius inversion, it should suffice to show that $\sum_{d|n}\frac12(d+1)\mu(\frac{n}{d})=f(n)$. The left hand side simplifies to $\frac12\phi(n)$, so again, I can prove the so-called intermediate step if I already have the final result. Is there another way to use Mobius inversion here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I think your proof is nicer than the one the book intended.  We can rewrite the sum 
$$
f(d) = \frac{1}{d} \sum_{(d,a) = 1} a
= \sum_{(d,a) = 1} \frac{a\cdot(n/d)}{n}
$$
Now note that as $a$ ranges across the values $\le d$ relatively prime to $d$, $(n/d)a$ ranges across the values $i\le n$ satisfying $(i,n) = n/d$.  We now can compute
$$
\frac{n+1}{2} = \frac{n^2+n}{2n}
= \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i}{n}
= \sum_{d\mid n} \sum_{(i,n) = n/d}\frac{i}{n}
= \sum_{d\mid n} \sum_{(d,a) = 1} \frac{a\cdot(n/d)}{n}
= \sum_{d\mid n} f(d)
$$
You then get $f(n) = \phi(n)/2$ for $n>1$ through Möbius inversion, as mentioned in comments.

Comment: Wow, I see. Thanks very much! There are a couple of typos in there, but I was able to follow it. Perhaps the problem is set up that way because the author wants readers to learn that particular style of proof. I'll keep it in mind for the next exercise which seems a bit similar.